# web.config transformation based on solution configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-config, transformation

Morning/afternoon/evening all.

I am trying to apply a web.config transformations as part of a Jenkins build. I have got the transformation running by adding the following to my csproj:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <TransformXml Source="Web.config" Transform="Web.$(Configuration).config" Destination="Web.config" />
</Target>
```

Which is great except for the fact that it now transforms the file when the solution is run locally. So I tried to prevent this by adding a condition to ONLY apply transformations for Jenkins builds. I added a solution configurations, set up the publish profile to use this, then tried to add a condition...

[image: Solution configuration dropdown]

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <TransformXml Source="Web.config" Transform="Web.$(Configuration).config" Destination="Web.config"  Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug Build'" />
</Target>
```

...and...... it no work :-(.

In fact transformations completely stop working when this condition is added (I can assert this by changing solution configurations locally and building and observing that the local web.config file is never changed, no matter which option is selected).

How do I get transformations run when and only when the solution configuration is set to 'Debug Build'?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use publish profile on build server you could use [profile specific web.config transform](http://sedodream.com/PermaLink,guid,fdcc88bf-95ac-4945-a49b-96d9d1ac35a5.aspx) to add your custom transform without modifying project files. You can simply right-click your publish profile in solution explorer and select `Add config transform`.

The resulting transform file will be named `web.[publishprofile].config` and this transform will run after configuration specific (Debug/Release) transform. It will only be executed when publishing/packaging using that publish profile.

---

If publish profile transformation does not fit your need, just add `/p:CustomConfigTransform=buildserver` msbuild argument on jenkins build server and test this property in your build script.

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <TransformXml Source="Web.config" Transform="Web.$(CustomConfigTransform).config" Destination="Web.config"  Condition="'$(CustomConfigTransform)' != ''" />
</Target>
```

There is no need to add new build configuration. Also i'm not sure if transforming to same file is supported.